# How do I fix my WaitForSeconds code that involves BoxColliders?

Tags: c#

Recently I have decided to start creating a game, and during this time I have run into many problems, most I have been able to fix myself but I'm having trouble with this. Basically, I want my code to make a Box Collider appear when clicked, and then disappear after a certain amount of time.

Here's my code:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(bruh())
}

void Update()
{
    IEnumerator bruh()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            this.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = true;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        }
        else
        {
            this.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your co-routine wasn't doing anything after it resumed from the yield return. I assume you want;

```cs
    ...
    this.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    this.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible new up the WaitForSeconds and then return that because it looks like you are just creating it not using it.